# How do I install a sails.js adapter that is published under a npm scope

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I've written a custom sails.js adapter for communicating with our internal API. The package is published as a private npm package at `@myscope/sails-my-adapter`. When trying to consume this in my sails app I do the following:

```
module.exports.adapters = {
  foo: {
    module: '@myscope/sails-my-adapter'
  }
};
```

This will throw `error: Are you sure that adapter is installed in this Sails app?` on sails startup. It works when I manually move the adapter out of the scope and just reference `sails-my-adapter` but that is not a long term solution.

Is this a problem with the way sails is consuming adapter modules or am I doing something wrong?